# How can I create index on nvarchar(max) datatype in sql?

Tags: sql, indexing

I have a table with `nvarchar(max)` datatype column. Max length of data in this column is `37000`, then I can't use `nvarchar(4000)`. How can I create index for this column? My data is Unicode text in Persian.

Comment: indexing a column of that length would seem largely pointless....suggest you look at Full Text Indexinhg

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/21624526/194717

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1- you could use it in an "INCLUDE"

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#example') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #example
END

CREATE TABLE #example (id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), name VARCHAR(MAX))

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_NC_temp_example_name ON #example(id) INCLUDE(name)
```

2-or You may consider to use  "CHECKSUM" method. It's inteded for buidling hash indexes, especially to improve indexing speed for indexing long character columns (as you have).
You can read more and find examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx

Comment: yeah, but what's the point of indexing a long text column? Other than a covering index (i.e. part of include, and even then its doubtful optimiser would use it)

Comment: That doesn't index the column. It just includes it in the index data.

Comment: Afarin Hossein you are the best.

Comment: I have quite valid use case. I have long URLs that I need to store and find fast. The max length for an index string might be around 840 characters but I need to index string that are over 2000 characters sometimes (don’t ask me why people have so long URLs). In my case I just need to find a exact match as fast as possible so storing a hash and indexing this works.

Answer (score 3):

Best is using `DROP_EXISTING = ON`, which does a rebuild using existing index.

Here is an example

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_NC_temp_example_name ON #example(id) INCLUDE(name)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
```